# Nginx vs Node.js - reverse proxy for multiple web-sockets servers

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

I want to host MULTIPLE WEBSOCKETS node servers (separate processes). It may be >1000 simultaneous connections. Also I want to log and control each connection and want to make it MEMORY efficient.
Is it a good idea to write reverse proxy in node.js?
Is it worse in anything than Nginx, pure Erlang or Scala?
Can even Nginx handle 1000+ websockets connections?
Does 1 connection freeze 1 Nginx thread? Is it memory efficient?

Comment: Did you try to read a bit about nginx and the other topics? Right now your answer reads like "I want a complete design of XYZ". PS: Did you hit limits with 1 Node.js instance and all the connections? :)

Comment: Excuse me for many questions. Processes must be separated because they belongs to different apps and I want to hermetize bugged ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy answer: nginx does not currently do HTTP/1.1 to upstreams, and thus definitely not websockets (nor does it have threads, but that's another story). A custom websockets proxy based on node.js is probably a good solution. You could also build something in Java; there are plenty of people building websockets services with it now.

Comment: This is no longer the case as of the most recent nginx release:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Answer (score 0):

You should consider **pure nginx**.

http://wiki.nginx.org/3rdPartyModules